# Two Dimension Arrays Re-Write

Tags: java, arrays

Hey this code works just fine, but it is difficult to read. I am looking for a way to do this better.

```
public void printArray(String[/*row*/][/*column*/] twoDiArray) {
    if (twoDiArray.length == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < twoDiArray[0].length; i++) {
            //prints attribute name and value
            attributeNameAndValue(twoDiArray[0][i],twoDiArray[1][i]);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Does not fit format standards :: 2d array :: two rows max :: first row name :: second row value");
    }
}
```

The part I seriously dislike is the length calls in the if statement and the for loop. Is there a better way to do this or is it just a sloppy section of java language.

Comment: To put this code in context, It is part of an XMLWriter project that can create XML documents to describe other objects.

Comment: I believe this is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have pairs name-value, if your names are unique, you should use `Map<String, Integer>` instead. Otherwise, create your own class called e.g. `Attribute` and use `List<Attribute>`:

```
public class Attribute {

    private final String name;
    private final int value;

    public Attribute(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

This gives you compile-time safety for the second dimension. Your code would look like this:

```
public void printArray(List<Attribute> attributes) {
    for (Attribute attribute : attributes) {
        attributeNameAndValue(attribute.getName(), attribute.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use new variable to save the value of `twoDiArray.length` and use new var below.

Answer (score 0):

This can certainly be cleaned up a little bit. A different approach as other people have mentioned would have much neater code. It's a little bizarre that you have row and column like that. Reversing the order would also make things cleaner:

```
public void printArray(String[/*row*/][/*column*/] twoDiArray){

    if(twoDiArray.length!=2){
        System.out.println("Does not fit format standards :: 2d array :: two rows max :: first row name :: second row value");
        return;
    }
    int len = twoDiArray[0].length;
    for(int i = 0; i<len.length; i++){
        //prints attribute name then value
        attributeNameAndValue(twoDiArray[0][i],twoDiArray[1][i]);
    }
}
```

Another thing would be to change `attributeNameAndValue` to accept `i` and `twoDiArray` for a "neater" call.

Answer (score 0):

another way to check array

```
public void printArray(String[/*row*/][/*column*/] twoDiArray){
  assert twoDiArray.length == 2;
  for(int i=0; i<twoDiArray[0].length; i++){
    attributeNameAndValue(kvp[i][0], kvp[i][1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Assert statement can be switched off depending on the JVM flags. If it is public API, it is recommended to throw `IllegalArgumentException` with meaningful error message. If it is for the internal, it shouldn't be there at all - test should be enough. Anyway, in DCS_Kurtis_IT_Manager's case, there is a printout there.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the code readability apply the java code conventions (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html).
Introduce variables rows and columns (for the number of rows and number of columns)

```
public void printArray(String[/*row*/][/*column*/] twoDiArray) {
    int rows = twoDiArray.length;
    if (rows != 2) {
        System.out.println("Does not fit format standards :: 2d array :: two rows max :: first row name :: second row value");
        return;
    }
    int columns = twoDiArray[0].length;
    for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
        //prints attribute name then value
        attributeNameAndValue(twoDiArray[0][column], twoDiArray[1][column]);
    }
}
```